# C# XML Fetching

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My XML looks so:

```
<sensor>
<data>26.7</data>
<data>54.53</data>
<log>false</log>
</sensor>
```

To retrieve the data fields in a list, I use:

```
List<string> list = xml.Root.Descendants("sensor").Elements("data").Select(element => element.Value).ToList();
```

And it works well.

Sometimes the XML looks like this (log = true):

```
<sensor>
<data>26.7</data>
<data>54.53</data>
<log>true</log>
</sensor>
```

And I want to ignore these values. How can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
 var lastUser = xml.Element("response").Descendants("sensor")
                   .First(u => u.Element("data") != null
                                    && u.Element("log").Value == "false");
```

But I only can retrieve of course only the first value.

Comment: I think @PLB nailed it :-)
As a suggestion: you should check out Linq to XML, I love it!

Comment: @Recipe Nope, Daniel Hilgrarth has nailed it. I was few seconds slower. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you use `First` if you don't want to select the first element? Use `Where` instead.

```
var data = xml.Element("response")
              .Descendants("sensor")
              .Where(x => ((string)x.Element("log")) == "false")
              .Elements("data")
              .Select(x => x.Value)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm relatively new with programming and did not know it was possible to achieve a "where" here. Thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.Where` instead of `.First` and you should be getting an array back?

Answer (score 0):

Use casting nodes to `bool` or to `double`:

```
 var data= xml.Element("response").Descendants("sensor")
              .Where(s => (bool)s.Element("log"))
              .Elements("data")
              .Select(d => (double)d)
              .ToList(); // produces List<double>
```

And yes @Daniel is right - `First` returns only first element from sequence which matches your conditions.

Also consider to use XPath

```
var data = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("response/sensor[log='true']/data")
               .Select(d => (double)d)
               .ToList();
```